# Function to create new variables using double for loop

Tags: r

I would like to write a function which creates a set of variables based on existing variable.

I am relatively new to R and trying to recreate a function I had in VBA.

Function called 'decay' should create a set of variables by applying different decay parameters on variable 'var'and save them in dataframe 'data'.

It should create a set of 19 variables which are named by concatenating existing variable name 'var' and decay parameter which takes values 5,10,15,20,25,30....95.

Then values are calculated as:

- The first value of new variable = first value of existing variable 'var'
- Any other subsequent value equals to corresponding value of existing variable 'var' + previous value of new variable*decay parameter/100

```
decay <- function(var, data) {
  for (i in 1:19) {
    paste(data$var, i*5)
    paste(data$var, i*5)[1] <- data$var[1]
    for (j in 1:length(var) - 1) {
      paste(data$var, i*5)[j + 1] <- data$var[j + 1] + paste(data$var, i*5)[j]*i*5
    }
  }
}
```

Output example:

```
var var5    var10   var15   var20
100 100 100 100 100
0   5   10  15  20
150 150 151 152 154
20  28  35  43  51
0   1   4   6   10
0   0   0   1   2
50  50  50  50  50
60  63  65  68  70
```

Comment: Dont really understand the output example, how do we interpret the output?

Comment: Could you copy and paste a sample of your data to the question?

Comment: We definitely more info about what "var" and "data" contain. It would also be good to know what you are trying to accomplish - not just replicating a VBA function in R. R has its own way of doing things so you can probably get the results you want faster and more efficiently by taking advantage of that. Creating a bunch of variables is just a step toward a final result and with R there are more efficient ways to store values. Your code uses paste(), but paste() does not create variables, it just concatenates text strings.

Answer (score 0):

It is weekly time series data. I have been using ts and xts object.This is a simplified example - real data has a few hundred variables and much longer variable names which makes reading code more difficult.

```
            var
04/01/2016  100
11/01/2016  0
18/01/2016  150
25/01/2016  20
01/02/2016  0
08/02/2016  0
15/02/2016  50
22/02/2016  60
```

The output is set of variables created by applying decay function to var. The first value equals to the fist value of var and any subsequent value is the sum of corresponding value in var + previous week's value of new variable *r/100 where r is decay parameter taking values 5,10,15,20...95. This could be written as following:

```
if t=1
new_var[t] = var[t]
if t>1
new_var[t] = var[t] + new_var[t-1]*r/100
```

I just would like variable names to be concatenation or original variable name (var) and decay rate r, e.g. var5 when r=5, var10 when r=10 etc.